# Glassfish and TLS performance degradation

Tags: java, http, ssl, https, glassfish

I have a Debian virtual machine with a GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 (build 1) configured with a Listener on 8080 port (no TLS) and another Listener with TLS on 8181 port with a valid certificate. Inside GlassFish there's an application that answer to HTTP requests.
If I do a POST from a client inside my network toward the 8080 port it takes an X time and with tcpdump I can see Y packets exchanged. **On 8181 port (with TLS)  time X and packet Y doubles.** Java application does not change its behavour if working in HTTP or HTTPS. I don't have any web server in front of my GlassFish server, I can directly send my requests to it.

Please, could someone point me in the right direction in order to understand the doubling of the packets and the response time? Is there any configuration I have to do in GF to increase performance with TLS enabled?

**update**
Glassfish is installed on a linux virtual machine
the application expose both a servlet and a web services, both receive an xml file (can be a big file, at the mmoment we are testing an xml around 15m)
The behaviour is the same:
    - when I try to send the file to the http port (8080) the number (and the volume) of packets transimetted is near a third part of the ones transmitted in SSL (8181)
    - this happens both using the servlet interface (the file into the body of the POST) or the web service interface (inside the SOAP envelope)

As example, http request performances:
    - completed in 1,5 sec
    - 446 packet sent

https request:
    - completed in 3,8 sec
    - 1236 packet sent

Comment: TLS has a nonzero performance overhead. The description you gave doesn't provide sufficient evidence to suggest there is a problem.

Comment: If you want direction, you need to provide a lot more information.  What OS?  What does your Java application do?  Can you post the source code?

Comment: Is an appplication that do crypto action on set of files. I'm editing the answer to give more information

Comment: @Andrew Henle: wich code do you are interested in? the problem is not on applicatino side, because the time is spent before the first application method is called, and on the client side we did test both with a java client and with a php version. The problem is that happens using the same code, just changing between called port (8080 or 8181)